# How to view the all contents if the screen has more content than it normally fits?

Tags: android

Here is my content_my_custom_home xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_my_custom_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.android.shustudenthelper.MyCustomHomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_my_custom_home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_shu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/shuhome_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_shu"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SHU STUDENT HELPER"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_selected_courses"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#FFCC00"
                android:dividerHeight="4px"
                android:state_activated="true"
                tools:listheader="COURSES:" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view_games"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#FFCC00"
                android:dividerHeight="4px"
                android:state_activated="true"
                tools:listheader="GAMES:" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view_events"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#FFCC00"
                android:dividerHeight="4px"
                android:state_activated="true"
                tools:listheader="EVENTS:" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem is, On screen it shows the contents until the screen is filled. It doesn't show me or allow me to scroll the rest of the contents. I have 3 list views in my xml and each will display 5 or more items on screen which I am not able to see all of them.

When I try to add scrollview for the layout, I am getting very odd output on my screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by odd output for scrollview? (Scrollview would have been my first choice for this problem)

Comment: If I use scrollview, Listview items are not shown but it shows only its listheader and it scrolls its items with in that Listview header.

Comment: Can you replace the ListViews with a RecyclerViews? And then wrap a NestedScrollView in? Else take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean); you will still need a NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scroll View then list will stop scrolling and if you remove scroll view then you are not able to see all the list. I am facing the same issue and answer to it is you cannot use list inside scroll view based on my findings. If you come across any solution Please do let me know. Thanks. 
There is also one work around for this hide all the list using android:visibility="false" and display only when they are need to be shown on button click and this will give you more space to display one list View at time.